# shell_exec() and IF usage

Tags: php

I am using `shell_exec()` like that:

```
$cmd = shell_exec("echo Hello!");
$cmd;
if(strpos($cmd, 'Hello!') !== false) {
    // $cmd contains 'Hello!'
}
```

and I wanted to know if the command gets executed 2 times in the previous code or no.

The 2 times which I mean are:

1. The line `$cmd;`
2. The IF statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Just once, The second time you are dealing with the output of the command, the line with ``$cmd;`` only is useless

Comment: You're only calling `shell_exec()` once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only executed once. Specifically when you call the `shell_exec` function, NOT when you use the `$cmd` variable, which holds the results of the function.

Have a look at the documented return value of the function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

> The output from the executed command

In other words, your code doesn't need the line `$cmd;` so could be rewritten like so:

```
$cmd = shell_exec("echo Hello!"); //command is fired here
if(strpos($cmd, 'Hello!') !== false) {
    // $cmd contains 'Hello!'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Question:

> I wanted to know if the command gets executed 2 times in the previous code

Answer:

No. Command executes only once when you call `shell_exec`.